# Deviceinfo without scanning

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can we know the bdaddress and rssi of all nearby ble devices without continuous lescanning? As the continuous lescan will consume more power and also we would not be able to properly make connection to a device while active scanning is going on in background.

The lescan background process also gets killed when we are disconnected from the connected state with any ble device

Also with how many peripherals can a central device be connected to simultanoeusly with bluez-4.101 stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right you cannot make connection while you are scanning for Low Energy devices and number of devices that can be connected to the central device is entirely dependent on the Software Stack you are using for BLE.
Like in CC2540  you can connect 3 devices at a time.

For RSSI and bluetooth address you refer function **le_advertising_report** according to bluez-4.101 stack.